# Minio openid sso always return to login page and session error invalid session

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, minio

I have install minio via docker-compose

```
version: '3'


services:
  minio:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minio
    container_name: minio
    hostname: minio
    restart: always
    # volumes:
    #   - './minio/data:/bitnami/minio/data'
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS=
```

and I config openid configuration with keycloak

- following youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOEkDiuYWI0
- set role policy instead claim

both way not work when redirect to keycloak and login successfully then it return to login page again

I look into network session of browser it return

```
{"detailedMessage":"Access Denied.","message":"invalid session"}
```

when in youtube miss config it show error on minio web but in my case it return to login page every time how can i solve this

Thank you

I want minio login via openid provider such as Keycloak or Google cloud